# Use MediaCodec and MediaExtractor to decode and code video

Tags: android, video, bitmap, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I need to decode a video into a sequence of bitmaps, such that I am able to modify them, and then compress them back to a video file in android.

I plan to manage this by using `getFrameAtTime` and saving it to an image sequence. Then I can modify images in the sequence and code it back to a movie. But I have two problem with this:

- First, as I read it, the `getFrameAtTime` is for creating thumbnails and will not guarantee returning the correct frame. This makes the video laggy.
- Secondly, saving the images and reading it back takes a long time.

I read that the proper way of doing the decode is with MediaExtractor, this is fine, but I only have examples to render it directly to a `surfaceView`. Is there any way for me to convert the `outputBuffer` to a bitmap?

I would need it to get it working with an api level of 16 and above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find a collection of useful examples on the [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) site.

In particular, the `ExtractMpegFramesTest` demonstrates how to decode a .mp4 file to `Bitmap`, and the `DecodeEditEncodeTest` decodes and re-encodes an H.264 stream, modifying the frames with a GLES shader.

Many of the examples use features introduced in API 18, such as `Surface` input to `MediaCodec` (which avoids a number of color-format issues), and `MediaMuxer` (which allows you to convert the raw H.264 elementary stream coming out of `MediaCodec` into a .mp4 file).  Some devices will allow you to extract video to YUV data in `ByteBuffer`, modify it, and re-encode it, but other devices extract to proprietary YUV color formats that may be rejected by the API 16 version of `MediaCodec`.

I'd recommend coding for API 18 (Android 4.3 "Jellybean" MR2) or later.

Comment: Well the problem is that I already saw this site, but unfortunately I must do it for API lvl 16. And even though it says ExtractMpegFramesTest.java requires API 16, when I try to build it it requires at least 17... So it's not an option.

Comment: You've got an uphill battle then.  Does it need to work generally or is this just being built for a specific device?  (I'll check into ExtractMpegFramesTest -- I didn't think it needed anything from 17+.)

Comment: Well that's the problem it needs to be generic and api lvl 16+... I got the getFrameAtTime solution to work without saving to png and speeding it up like this quite a few times, but still I may have the issue it will extract some frames two times, which would make the video laggy, and I still have no Idea how could I add audio to it. So any suggestion for splitting up the video to bitmaps and creating a new video file with audio would be appreciated, but it needs to work with 16+

Comment: The ExtractMpegFramesTest example has been modified to work with API 16 (needed EGL 1.0 rather than EGL 1.4 -- cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495863/mediacodec-extractmpegframestest-example-mismatch/ ).  There is no facility for creating a .mp4 file (either video only or video+audio) until API 18 introduced the `MediaMuxer` class, so if you need that you may want to investigate external libraries (perhaps ffmpeg).

Comment: @fadden hi, I'm trying to get the ExtractMpegFramesTest example to work, but the SurfaceTexture onFrameAvailable() call is never made, or made too late. I added a question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457623/surfacetextures-onframeavailable-method-always-called-too-late

Comment: In the end I made it with ffmpeg, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

There are many people saying that the method `onFrameAvailable()` is never called. Well, the **listener** should be in a different thread than the main thread. To set the listener do this: (where this is the class listener that implements `SurfaceTexture.IOnFrameAvailableListener`):

```
mSurfaceTexture.SetOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
```