# mediacodec ExtractMpegFramesTest example mismatch

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

I tried to run [This example](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest.java.txt) from [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) and I think that there is a mismatch.

they write "ExtractMpegFramesTest.java (requires 4.1, API 16) " so the minimum API required is 16,
but I look over the code and they use "import android.opengl.EGL14;" which required minimum API 17.

Has anyone encountered this problem and succeeded to solve it?(succeeded to save 10 frames on Android 4.1 device)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated [the site](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest) to have two copies of the source file, one that uses EGL 1.0 and one that uses EGL 1.4.  I did a quick test with the SDK, creating an app for API 16, to confirm that it's no longer using post-4.1 APIs.  I haven't tried it on an actual device running 4.1 however.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the update,There are no errors now. but there is a bug, after this line : boolean doRender = (info.size != 0); ,"doRender" get false all the time on galaxy s3, on galaxy s4 this example work well.

Comment: Ok, The example is finally work!
I just don't use the doRender variable.

Comment: @Itay: I am trying to make ExtractMpegFramesTest work. Mainly I have a main activity with a button, and a class of ExtractMpegFramesTest. After I click the button, it will create an object of ExtractMpegFramesTest, and run the object.testExtractMpegFrames(). But it does not work. It complained java.lang.RuntimeException: frame wait timed out. Would you give me a clue to solve it? See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139205/android-mediacodec-encoding-falis-because-no-sync-frames-for-video-track           Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long%29) in order to extract frames from a video file. It's available since API level 10.

Comment: I tried Media meta retriever before, but I need to decode 300 frames of 1920x1080 so it takes too long for me.

Comment: That call exists to extract a single thumbnail from a video stream.  It's really not meant for extracting all frames from a video.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not, I just didn't see a request for extracting 'all' (or 300) frames from a video in OP's question...

Comment: The other problem with `getFrameAtTime()` is that it's time-based, rather than frame-based.  If the video wasn't recorded at a constant frame rate -- maybe it has a couple of frames, then nothing for a few seconds, then there's a few more -- you'll end up "creating" frames unnecessarily.  Depending on the intended use of the data this may or may not matter.  (See 4.4's `screenrecord` for an example of something that records video this way -- it only outputs a frame when the screen changes.)