# Decode and Encode MP4 with MediaCodec

Tags: android, input, output, video-processing, android-mediacodec

I doesn't matter what I am trying I always get this Exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Surface frame wait timed out

I tried several possible solutions but I always come back to this Exception. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

The first Method:

```
    public void EncodeDecode() {
    try {
        VideoChunks outputData = new VideoChunks();
        extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        MediaCodec decoder = null;
        MediaCodec encoder = null;
        InputSurface inputSurface = null;
        OutputSurface outputSurface = null;


        extractor.setDataSource(filePath);

        for (int i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
            inputFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = inputFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
                extractor.selectTrack(i);
                mimeType = mime;
                break;
            }
        }

        mWidth = inputFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH);
        mHeight = inputFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT);

        Log.v(TAG,"mime "+mimeType+ " Key: "+mWidth+" "+ mHeight);
        // Create an encoder format that matches the input format.  (Might be able to just
        // re-use the format used to generate the video, since we want it to be the same.)
        MediaFormat outputFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mimeType, mWidth, mHeight);
        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
                (int) MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, mHeight*mWidth*15);
        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE,
                60);
        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 30);
        outputData.setMediaFormat(outputFormat);
        encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mimeType);
        encoder.configure(outputFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        inputSurface = new InputSurface(encoder.createInputSurface());
        inputSurface.makeCurrent();
        encoder.start();
        // OutputSurface uses the EGL context created by InputSurface.
        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mimeType);
        outputSurface = new OutputSurface(mWidth,mHeight);
        outputSurface.changeFragmentShader(FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        decoder.configure(inputFormat, outputSurface.getSurface(), null, 0);
        decoder.start();
        editVideoData(extractor, decoder, outputSurface, inputSurface, encoder, outputData);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Calling this Method:

```
    private void editVideoData(MediaExtractor extractor, MediaCodec decoder,
                           OutputSurface outputSurface, InputSurface inputSurface, MediaCodec encoder,
                           VideoChunks outputData) {
    boolean inputDone = false;
    boolean outputDone = false;
    boolean decoderDone = false;
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000;

    ByteBuffer[] decoderInputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    int inputChunk = 0;
    int outputCount = 0;
    File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/dir1/dir2/OK.MP4");
    MediaMuxer mMuxer;
    try {

        mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

        while (!outputDone) {
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "edit loop");
            // Feed more data to the decoder.
            if (!inputDone) {

                int inputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer buffer = decoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                    int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                    if (sampleSize < 0) {
                        inputChunk++;
                        // End of stream -- send empty frame with EOS flag set.
                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, 0L,
                                MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                        inputDone = true;
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "sent input EOS (with zero-length frame)");
                    } else {
                        // Copy a chunk of input to the decoder.  The first chunk should have
                        // the BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG flag set.
                        buffer.clear();
                        Log.v(TAG,"samplesize: "+sampleSize +" sampleTime: "+extractor.getSampleTime() + " info.flag: "+info.presentationTimeUs);
                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                        extractor.advance();

                        inputChunk++;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "input buffer not available");
                }
            }
            // Assume output is available.  Loop until both assumptions are false.
            boolean decoderOutputAvailable = !decoderDone;
            boolean encoderOutputAvailable = true;
            while (decoderOutputAvailable || encoderOutputAvailable) {
                // Start by draining any pending output from the encoder.  It's important to
                // do this before we try to stuff any more data in.
                int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                if (encoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                    // no output available yet
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "no output from encoder available");
                    encoderOutputAvailable = false;
                } else if (encoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                    encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "encoder output buffers changed");
                } else if (encoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                    MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();

                    int dstIndex = mMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);

                    mMuxer.start();

                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "started: encoder output format changed: " + newFormat+" dstIndex"+ dstIndex);
                } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
                } else { // encoderStatus >= 0
                    ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
                    if (encodedData == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                    }
                    // Write the data to the output "file".
                    if (info.size != 0) {
                        encodedData.position(info.offset);
                        encodedData.limit(info.offset + info.size);
                        mMuxer.writeSampleData(0, encodedData, info);

                         outputData.addChunk(encodedData, (int)info.flags, info.presentationTimeUs);
                        outputCount++;
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "encoder output " + info.size + " bytes");
                    }
                    outputDone = (info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0;
                    encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                }
                if (encoderStatus != (int) MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                    // Continue attempts to drain output.
                    continue;
                }
                // Encoder is drained, check to see if we've got a new frame of output from
                // the decoder.  (The output is going to a Surface, rather than a ByteBuffer,
                // but we still get information through BufferInfo.)
                if (!decoderDone) {
                    int decoderStatus = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                    if (decoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                        // no output available yet
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "no output from decoder available");
                        decoderOutputAvailable = false;
                    } else if (decoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                        //decoderOutputBuffers = decoder.GetOutputBuffers();
                        if (VERBOSE)
                            Log.d(TAG, "decoder output buffers changed (we don't care)");
                    } else if (decoderStatus == (int) MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                        // expected before first buffer of data
                        MediaFormat newFormat = decoder.getOutputFormat();
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "decoder output format changed: " + newFormat);
                    } else if (decoderStatus < 0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result from decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + decoderStatus);
                    } else { // decoderStatus >= 0
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "surface decoder given buffer "
                                + decoderStatus + " (size=" + info.size + ")");
                        // The ByteBuffers are null references, but we still get a nonzero
                        // size for the decoded data.
                        boolean doRender = (info.size != 0);
                        // As soon as we call releaseOutputBuffer, the buffer will be forwarded
                        // to SurfaceTexture to convert to a texture.  The API doesn't
                        // guarantee that the texture will be available before the call
                        // returns, so we need to wait for the onFrameAvailable callback to
                        // fire.  If we don't wait, we risk rendering from the previous frame.
                        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, doRender);
                        if (doRender) {
                            // This waits for the image and renders it after it arrives.
                            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "awaiting frame");
                            outputSurface.awaitNewImage();
                            outputSurface.drawImage();
                         //   outputSurface.saveFrame(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/test.jpg", mWidth, mHeight);
                            // Send it to the encoder.
                            inputSurface.setPresentationTime(info.presentationTimeUs * 1000);
                            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "swapBuffers");
                            inputSurface.swapBuffers();
                        }
                        if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                            // forward decoder EOS to encoder
                            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "signaling input EOS");
                            if (WORK_AROUND_BUGS) {
                                // Bail early, possibly dropping a frame.
                                return;
                            } else
                                encoder.signalEndOfInputStream();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (inputChunk != outputCount) {
            throw new RuntimeException("frame lost: " + inputChunk + " in, " +
                    outputCount + " out");
        }
        mMuxer.release();
        mMuxer = null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

And this is the complete Log

```
    02-02 10:54:33.086    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 V/MainActivity﹕ mime video/mp4v-es Key: 640 368
 02-02 10:54:33.116    7298-7321/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 W/ACodec﹕ do not know color format 0x7fa30c06 = 2141391878
 02-02 10:54:33.116    7298-7321/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 W/ACodec﹕ do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
 02-02 10:54:33.116    7298-7321/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 W/ACodec﹕ do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
 02-02 10:54:33.116    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.006.020 - CR771817 ()
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
Build Date: 03/04/15 Wed
Local Branch:
Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.006.020
Local Patches: NONE
Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
 02-02 10:54:33.176    7298-7327/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.mpeg4] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
 02-02 10:54:33.176    7298-7327/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 W/ACodec﹕ do not know color format 0x7fa30c03 = 2141391875
 02-02 10:54:33.206    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ edit loop
 02-02 10:54:33.206    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 V/MainActivity﹕ samplesize: 35660 sampleTime: 0 info.flag: 0
 02-02 10:54:33.206    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ started: encoder output format changed: {height=368, width=640, mime=video/mp4v-es, what=1869968451, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=30,capacity=30]} dstIndex0
 02-02 10:54:33.206    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ encoder output 30 bytes
 02-02 10:54:33.216    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ no output from encoder available
 02-02 10:54:33.226    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ no output from decoder available
 02-02 10:54:33.226    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ edit loop
 02-02 10:54:33.226    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 V/MainActivity﹕ samplesize: 4000 sampleTime: 40000 info.flag: 0
 02-02 10:54:33.236    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ no output from encoder available
 02-02 10:54:33.246    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ no output from decoder available
 02-02 10:54:33.246    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ edit loop
 02-02 10:54:33.246    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 V/MainActivity﹕ samplesize: 5934 sampleTime: 80000 info.flag: 0
 02-02 10:54:33.256    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ no output from encoder available
 02-02 10:54:33.256    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ decoder output buffers changed (we don't care)
 02-02 10:54:33.266    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ no output from encoder available
 02-02 10:54:33.276    7298-7327/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 W/ACodec﹕ do not know color format 0x7fa30c03 = 2141391875
 02-02 10:54:33.286    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ decoder output format changed: {mime=video/raw, crop-top=0, crop-right=639, slice-height=384, color-format=2141391875, height=368, width=640, what=1869968451, crop-bottom=367, crop-left=0, stride=640}
 02-02 10:54:33.296    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ no output from encoder available
 02-02 10:54:33.296    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ surface decoder given buffer 0 (size=368640)
 02-02 10:54:33.296    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ awaiting frame
 02-02 10:54:33.296    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 V/Output﹕ while !FrameAvailable
 02-02 10:54:33.796    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1, PID: 7298
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1.
```

dsadsdasd

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Surface frame wait timed out
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Surface frame wait timed out
>
> at com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1.OutputSurface.awaitNewImage(OutputSurface.java:256)
>
> at com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1.MainActivity.editVideoData(MainActivity.java:235)
>
> at com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1.MainActivity.EncodeDecode(MainActivity.java:98)
>
> at com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
>
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
>
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)

```
02-02 10:54:40.003    7298-7332/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 E/MPEG4Writer﹕ There are no sync frames for video track
02-02 10:54:40.003    7298-7332/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 E/MPEG4Writer﹕ notify Error:-1007 track1
02-02 10:54:40.003    7298-7332/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1         W/MPEG4Writer﹕ 0-duration samples found: 1
```

**Edit1:**

I don't get the Exception anymore but I still get an empty output. Whenever I run the DecodeEditEncodeTest.java class i get an empty output as well.

The inputBufIndex is always -1.

> int inputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);

So far I tried running the application on a HTC One and a Samsung Galaxy 4. Both have a Qualcomm Snapdragon 600 Prozessor. I also tried to run it on a Samsung Galaxy S5. That did not work out as well.

I don't know if it is part of the problem. The Log shows now this warning for each frame:

```
    mediacodecso1 W/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3634>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457623/surfacetextures-onframeavailable-method-always-called-too-late ?

Comment: I will check it out. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: Commenting the line "h.join();" fixed the exception. But unfortunately I still get
 `02-02 10:54:33.216    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ no output from encoder available
 02-02 10:54:33.226    7298-7298/com.example.q389125.mediacodecso1 D/MainActivity﹕ no output from decoder available` I could not find a way to fix this yet.

Comment: I struggled with this myself for a little while. There is somewhere in your code that you are not releasing the buffer before attempting to dequeue it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Devsil, I am looking into that but I could't find anything where I didn't release the buffer before I  dequeue it again.

Comment: Do you have data passed to the input?