# How to split a video into smaller parts with Android MediaCodec?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

In my app I would like to split a selected video from the gallery into smaller pieces of the same length. For example, if I want to split a 25 second video into pieces of up to 10 seconds, I would get 3 videos (10 sec, 10 sec, 5 sec).

So far I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44653626/11815223) on Stack Overflow that allows me to just choose the beginning and end of a video.

How can I use MediaCodec to achieve my goal?

Comment: AFAIK `MediaCodec` you can only trim video at key-frames `SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC`.

Answer (score 0):

To produce segments of exact duration you would need to re-encode the video and possibly the audio track using pairs of decoders and encoders (instances of `MediaCodec`) along with a `MediaExtractor` and a separate `MediaMuxer` for each output segment.

Each time you reach the end of a segment (looking at the presentation time of the frame) you would send an end-of-stream signal to the encoder and then restart it.

For audio you would also need to split some of the decoded buffers at the segment boundaries.